# cakephp default value of an input date (last day of month)

Tags: php, date, cakephp

I'm trying to put the last day of the actual month on an input date...

So for exemple, we are the 28 **april** so the default value of my input should be the 30

I'm using cakephp 2.X (I don't know which version because it's not my project)

here is my input:

```
<?= 
$this->Form->input('fin', array('type'  =>  'date', 'label' => "Date Validité", 'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'separator'  => '&nbsp;', 'minYear' => '2013', 'div' => false)); 
?>
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for my poor english :)

Comment: Thank you ! Works great:

 <?php  $date = date('Y-m-d'); ?>
 <?= $this->Form->input('fin', array('selected' => date("Y-m-t", strtotime($date)), 'type'    =>  'date', 'label' => "Date Validité", 'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'separator'  => '&nbsp;', 'minYear' => '2013', 'div' => false)); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try with `date("t", strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))` -

```
$this->Form->input('fin', array('type'  =>  'date', 'label' => "Date Validité", 'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'separator'  => '&nbsp;', 'minYear' => '2013', 'div' => false, value=> date("t", strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))));
```

Comment: Didn't work but thank you :)

Comment: @ClémentD What html it is generating?